# Can SASS calculate the difference between a value and the next whole number?

Tags: sass

I have a SASS mixin. At the moment the $line-height needs to be whole 
numbers so 1, 2, etc but not 1.4, 2.2 etc.

```
@mixin text-style($line-height) {
  line-height: $line-height rem;
}
```

I need to extend it so that you don't have to use whole numbers. But in order to do this I need to add padding to maintain the vertical rhythm. The padding value is the difference between $line-height and the next whole number.

So if $line-height is 1, 2, etc then no padding is added.

If $line-height is 1.5 then 0.5 padding needs to be added.

If $line-height is 1.1 then 0.9 padding needs to be added.

Can SASS do this?

Comment: SASS knows math functions such as floor/ceil, http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Comment: ... and with these functions you could calculate the difference like this `$padding: ceil($line-height) - $line-height;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another mixin which will take the same input `$line-height` as an argument and use the logic that [Marvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3162554/marvin) wrote in his comment:

```
@mixin add-padding($line-height) {
  $padding-to-add: ceil($line-height) - $line-height;
  padding: $padding-to-add;
}
```

Now you can use it in your styling as follows:

```
.selector {
  @include add-padding(2.4rem);
}
```